# A query that does a lot of reads, but plan is OK

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I´m experiencing a strange behaviour in a specific query in the `SQL Server 2008 R2`. I´ve got a query that does 19 million reads and is very time-consuming and when I try to check its cached plan, the plan is OK, without any problem what so ever.

After doing the `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, the same query does 400 reads (taking 16 ms). The conclusion is that somehow the query is executed with the wrong plan, but that´s not the information I got from the SQL Server.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Find below the queries I used to extract the plan :

```
SELECT
sqltext.TEXT,
sqlplan.query_plan,
req.session_id [Session ID],
p.kpid [Thread ID],
p.program_name,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.logical_reads,
req.blocking_session_id,
req.transaction_id,
req.total_elapsed_time,
req.wait_resource
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req inner join
     sys.sysprocesses p on req.session_id = p.spid
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(req.plan_handle) AS sqlplan
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

And

```
SELECT db.name,
cp.objtype AS ObjectType,
OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
cp.usecounts AS ExecutionCount,
st.TEXT AS QueryText,
qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st 
INNER JOIN sys.sysdatabases db on st.dbid = db.dbid
where st.TEXT like '%part_of_query%'
```

Another info is that the query plan is the same before and after the free cache command.

Cheers

UPDATE

The STATISTICS IO:

Table 'VIA_ACL_DETAIL'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_ENTITY'. Scan count 0, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_ACCOUNT'. Scan count 0, logical reads 6, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_RESOURCE'. Scan count 0, logical reads 15, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_ACL'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_BUSINESS_NODE_USER'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'VIA_USER'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

[Image of the Execution Plan](http://s28.postimg.org/p37heu4l9/Untitled.png)